# IndexOutOfBoundException when trying to write in response in wicket

Tags: java, wicket

I have a wicket page like this:

```
public final class Services extends WebPage {
    public Services() {
        super();   
    }

    public Services(PageParameters params) {
        StringValue serviceType = params.get("name");
        if("report".equals(serviceType.toString())) {
            this.getResponse().write("HelloWorld");
        }
    }
}
```

and it's html is empty.
when I call URL of this page I see this error

```
Index: 0, Size: 0
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:604)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:382)
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableList.get(Collections.java:1211)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.Markup.get(Markup.java:130)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRender(Component.java:2356)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2307)
    at org.apache.wicket.Page.renderPage(Page.java:1010)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.WebPageRenderer.renderPage(WebPageRenderer.java:121)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.WebPageRenderer.respond(WebPageRenderer.java:271)
    at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.RenderPageRequestHandler.respond(RenderPageRequestHandler.java:165)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:861)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerStack.execute(RequestHandlerStack.java:64)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.execute(RequestCycle.java:261)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:218)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:289)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequestCycle(WicketFilter.java:259)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequest(WicketFilter.java:201)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:282)
...
```

i don't know really what is wrong in my simple wicket page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wicket ever expects some markup in the associated HTML template to the code. The line that is the originator of your Exception is in **Component.class** see

```
private final void internalRender()
{
...
    MarkupElement elem = markup.get(0);
...
}
```

That code gets a 'root' element of the associated markup. A code without any markup is a non-sence in Wicket.

**TIP:** If you just want to handle a request, mount a shareable resource or some of other resources other then a page.